# Query - get_all - Multiple Inputs - Pydgraph

Tags: dgraph

As stated over here [link](https://github.com/dgraph-io/pydgraph#run-a-query), it query for 'Alice' and it results for all the information for 'Alice'.

What if I have 'n' inputs in order to get all information say n=2 'Alice', 'Bob', etc.

What would be the query?
I tried to define `variables_1 = {'$b': 'Alice, Bob'}`
and defining `$b: list` in query list or array but not working.

Comment: Tentative solution provided in this [link](https://discuss.dgraph.io/t/query-get-all-multiple-inputs/3037)